# How to get time series data in angular

Tags: angular, api, frontend

What is the proper angular method for getting all of the time series data from an API in which the keys are unknown such as from [here](https://corona.lmao.ninja/v3/covid-19/historical/all?lastdays=all)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well there is not a standard way to do such but you can loop through the properties of the object using normal for.. in

```
for (let day in data) {
  console.log(pet); // "species"
}
```

For in will actually loop through the object properties inside the object.